# I want comment instructions to be displayed in French, like e.g. no more "leave a comment" but "laisser un commentaire"

Tags: wordpress-theming

I copied `content.php` into my child theme folder `ChildOfTwenty-Thirteen` and amended a few lines:

```
<?php if ( comments_open() && ! is_single() ) : ?> 
<div class="comments-link">
    <!-- Change message text so they display in French -->
    <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Laissez un commentaire', 'twentythirteen' ) . '</span>', __( 'Vous avez 1 commentaire', 'twentythirteen' ), __( 'Consultez le(s) % commentaire(s)', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?>
</div>
<!-- .comments-link -->
<?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
```

When I refresh the page, the instructions flash in French for 1 second, then it reverts to English "Leave a comment", etc... Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Download the French version here:
http://fr.wordpress.org/

Overwrite everything except the wp-content folder and the wp-config.php file (in root directory), after you've overwritten everything you have to change the language setting in your wp-config.php file.

Comment: I didn't precise it but I did install WP in French of course. All the admin is in French, except Diskus for the comments. I installed Diskus in French as well but it doesn't work perfectly.

Comment: Should have told us that you're using a plugin for your comments, obvikously Diskus doesn't use the theme file but it uses their own file. Check the Diskus folder in the plugins directory.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't precise it but I did install WP in French of course. All the admin is in French, except Diskus for the comments. I installed Diskus in French as well but it doesn't work perfectly. 
Actually, I just realised my code is working for categories, etc... just not for posts. That's because I wrote "!is single()", so... if I view an article, I am in a "is_single()" case and my code cannot apply.
What threw me though is that the French stayed for 2-3 seconds each time I refreshed the page and then the English got back. That's what I don't get. If the "Leave a comment" had stayed all the time, I wouldn't have bothered posting my question.
Thanks anyway